# How can i add a collider for the elevator to prevent from the character to walk through the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The character can enter the elevator but the problem is that he can also walk through the walls from sides and behind.

And if i add a box collider or any other collider/s they will prevent from the character to enter the elevator. It's not my elevator object it was made in blender.

[image: Elevator]

Comment: SO is for programming questions, you'll probably have more look getting an answer @ the unity forums. From memory unity let s you generate a mesh collider so you could look into that, and if it doesn't work, then you can frankenstein colliders together from native shapes and child them to the elevator object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Compound Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) instead of Mesh Collider.

Create new empty GameObjects called back, front, right, left, top and bottom 
then attach Box Collider to each one. Manually resize and move each one to match the size of the elevator on all sides.

Once that is done, put them in a parent empty GameObject then put that parent GameObject under your elevator GameObject so that the colliders will move/rotate with the elevator. Finally, disable or move the front Collider GameObject via code when you want to allow the player to enter inside the elevator.

The image below shows example of what individual collider should look like and the final look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These sorts of questions are better off in the [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/index.html), as this isn't a programming question. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

To answer your question though,

Find the mesh in your Project Files in Unity, there is a checkbox for 'Generate Colliders' - check this box and press apply.
Finally, on the GameObject with the mesh, add a `MeshCollider` component.

If the model is set up correctly, your mesh collider should now use the model for collision.

If this does not work, as an alternative, you can use cubes with colliders and 'build' the collision mesh yourself, and parent the objects to the same object so they move with the lift, before disabling the `MeshRenderer` component so they will not render.